# Filtering a ViewPanel Control

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a viewPanel control and I've added a edit box and a button that reads "Apply Filter" above my view.  If the user enters something I want to filter the view based on what is entered.  So let's say that the edit box is going to be used to filter the 'CompanyName' column of the view.  I've the following code in the "onclick" event under SSJS for my button.

```
var viewPanel1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1");
var domView:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewData = viewPanel1.getData();
var filtervalue = getComponent('cmbCompanyName').getValue();
domView.setKeys(filtervalue);
```

I don't understand how the setKeys knows that I'm filtering on the 'CompanyName' column just by me passing what the user entered.  The above code does not produce an error, it just doesn't produce the desired results.  If I can see 'my Company' in the view.  I enter 'my Company' in my edit box and then click the 'apply filter' button and the view is then completely blank.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A simple mistake I made many times:  Is the first column of the view sorted??

Answer (score 1):

You'd get an easier solution without coding SSJS if you'd bind your filter edit box value to a **view scope variable** and use this view scope variable as dominoView's `keys` attribute.

You'd only have to partially refresh the viewPanel1 clicking on button "Apply Filter" without any additional code.

```xml
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView
        var="view1"
        viewName="viewCompanies"
        keys="#{viewScope.cmbCompanyName}">
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    value="#{viewScope.cmbCompanyName}"></xp:inputText>
<xp:button
    value="Filter"
    id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="viewPanel1">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:viewPanel
    value="#{view1}"
    id="viewPanel1">
    ...
</xp:viewPanel>
```

`keys` attribute filters always the first sorted column in view. So, in your case the CompanyName column has to be the first sorted column.

In case `keys` attribute contains an array then first element filters first sorted column, second element sub-filters second sorted column and so on.

If you have several filters which shall work on *different* sorted columns then you can "switch" the "first" sorted column to another sorted column with dominoView's attribute

```
sortColumn="otherColumnName"
```

The "otherColumnName" can be calculated with SSJS depending on which button was clicked or which filter edit fields are filled.

Comment: No it wasn't!  I tried the viewScope way and it worked like a charm.   I'm going to do some experimenting with getting it to work with the sorted keys though.  Seems like if I have multiple sorts that may be the way to go.  Thanks for help.

Comment: Great! I added a description to my answer how you can switch between sorted columns for keys filtering.